# Adding Google Account in Internet Account on Mac Book Pro: Authentication fails

Tags: macbook-pro, gmail, accounts, google, authentication

On My 2019 Mac Book Pro, under internet accounts, I want to add a google account. It prompts me with opening a browser (Safari is the default browser). After a few seconds a window opens saying "Authentication Failed, please try again later". I have a google account with 2 factor authorisation, but I don't even get to the point where I can enter a password. This is particularly annoying since I need the Google Calendar in my Mac Calendar App.
I'm running MacOs 11.1 with Safari 14.0.2. I'm using Avast and CleanMyMac, if that is of any relevance. I'm mostly interested in getting the calendar integration to work, so if there is a workaround it would be much appreciated.
This problems also occurs when booted in safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

The problem disappeared today, so I guess there was some problem with google.